# Is the given function $f$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, sorgenfrey-line

Problem

Let $\mathbb{R}_l$ denote the reals with lower limit topology, and let $\mathbb{R}_l\times \mathbb{R}_l$ have the product topology. Then the map $f:\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}_l\to\mathbb{R}_l$ defined by $f(x,y)=xy$ is continuous. (True or False)

I am trying to use Local formulation of continuity (Munkres) which states that $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if $X$ can be written as the union of open sets $U_\alpha$ such that $f|U_\alpha$ is continuous for each $\alpha$. Can it be solved using this? If not then how to solve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO. Let $V=[0,1)$. Let $p=<-1,0>\in R_l^2.$ We have $f(p)=0 . $ Suppose $U$ is a nbhd of  $p$  such that $$\forall q\in U\; ( f(q)\in V). $$ We have $U\supset [-1,-1+r)\times [0,s)$ for some $r,s \in R^+ . $ But then $q=<-1,s/2>\in U$ and $f(q)=-s/2\not \in  V, $ a contradiction.

Good Q nevertheless.

Comment: There are a few points I can't understand so I haven't accepted the answer yet : What does $<-1,0>$ mean? and a little more elaboration might help...Thanks +1 as of now.

Comment: $<-1.0>$ is an ordered pair.  Favored by some writers, as $(-1,0)$ can also denote an interval.... $V$  is a nbhd of  $f(p). $  If $f$ were continuous at $p$  then there must exist a nbhd $U$ of  $p$ such that  $ q\in U\implies f(q)\in V. $  But this is not so. So $f$ is not continuous  at $p$.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another interesting result for $R_l^2$ is that it is not a normal ($T_4$) space,because it is separable (has a countable dense subset),but $\{(x,-x):x\in R_l\}$ is a closed discrete subspace whose cardinal is the cardinal of $R.$

Comment: Ok all that's great but how did you know like how to find a counter-example? Did you know it from before or did you find it after reading the question? Any tips on finding such counter examples?

Comment: I didn't know it. I drew a picture  of $f^{-1}[a,a+b) $  with $b>0$, and was trying to prove it was open and felt that something was wrong.  So I looked at a particular simple case, i.e. is $f$ continuous at some (any) member of $f^{-1}\{0\}$ ? If you have trouble proving a generality, it may be  because it's false. So look at some simplest special cases, and always   try to use the basic def'ns  first, (In this Q, any equivalent def'n of continuity), before looking for deeper theorems to use.